# What happens if tmpfs reached the limit that defined in percentage

Tags: linux, rhel, ram, tmpfs, ramdisk

lets say we defined the following in `/etc/fstab`

`tmpfs  /data   tmpfs   size=90%   0 0`
And then we

```
mount -a
```

Now `/data` is with `tmpfs`

What could be happens on the following scenario

case that `/data` reached the `90%` of RAM memory ( `tmpfs` reached 90% ) is it mean in this case any higher of `90%` will used the swap memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
If your physical memory is not able to be served the percentage portion (90%),eventually swap will be used. When IO is larger than the designated percentage IO errors occur.

**Long answer:**
The percentage represents the portion of your memory(physical memory + swap partition or swap file}. Assuming  that you have 1TiB DIMM (RAM)  and set swap 100GiB like according to Redhat’s recommendation, theoretically speaking any IO to /data above 0.989 TiB will occur IO errors like every other filesystem does. In practice, since memory and swap space is being used by all the other stuff beware of the deadlocks caused by [OOM wont be able to clear out memory in case of overgrowth.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)

Here is a the proof about what I am talking, executed on my laptop:

1. State of the system before write IO.

   ```
   ceto@dell:~$ free
                 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
   Mem:        8041716     2110100     3461592      208904     2470024     5464012
   Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
   ceto@dell:~$ cat /etc/fstab | grep data
   tmpfs         /data         tmpfs     rw,nodev,nosuid,size=90%    0    0
   ceto@dell:~$ mv rh/rhel-8.1-x86_64-dvd.iso /var/lib/libvirt/images/^C
   ceto@dell:~$ findmnt /data
   TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
   /data  tmpfs  tmpfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=7237548k
   ceto@dell:~$ df /data
   Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
   tmpfs            7237548     0   7237548   0% /data
   ```
2. I used the script below to generate the IO which is above 90 percent of the /data mount path.

   ```
   ceto@dell:~$ cat deadlock.sh 
   dd if=/dev/urandom of=/data/test.img bs=16M count=454  > deadlock.txt 2>&1
   df /data >> deadlock.txt 
   free >> deadlock.txt
   sleep 1 
   rm -rf /data/test.img 
   sync /data
   ```
3. Lets generate the IO and see what happens

   ```
   ceto@dell:~$ sudo sh deadlock.sh
   ```
4. In output file wee see that the IO errors occurs and the system gets sloppy

   ```
   ceto@dell:~$ cat deadlock.txt 
   dd: error writing '/data/test.img': No space left on device
   442+0 records in
   441+0 records out
   7411249152 bytes (7.4 GB, 6.9 GiB) copied, 39.6605 s, 187 MB/s
   Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
   tmpfs            7237548 7237548         0 100% /data
                 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
   Mem:        8041716     2284836      126108     5358092     5630772      139840
   Swap:       2097148     2097084          64
   ```